# Replace String with Wildcard

Tags: string, replaceall

Is it possible to replaceall on a string using wildcards?
For example

```
string adder;
adder = '[Test | 123 ! xyz]';
string replaced;
replaced = adder.replaceall('|%!','');

System.AssertEquals(replaced,'Test xyz');
```

Here I am using % as wildcard but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replaceAll) for the `replaceAll()` method says that it accepts a [Regular Expression](http://regexr.com/) as the first argument.  If you wanted to get rid of everything between `|` and `!` inclusive you can use `adder.replaceAll('(\\|.*!)','');`.

Comment: What I want to do is something like this: [Term: 1 | Vol: 1| Result:1][Term:2|Vol:2|Result:2] and if i want to grab all the terms do ReplaceAll('| Vol: % ]',']') so the result is [Term:1][Term:2]

Comment: @AverageJoeVBA As stated in the answer (implicitly), you need to "escape" |, which normally means "OR", and you also need to escape the "\" that you use to escape the |, because that has special meaning in Apex Code (also an escape), so you have to write `\\|` to match a literal | character.

Comment: Awesome Jeff thanks for the updated answer. Worked to perfection, saved me some rework of splitting out the build of a string throughout a controller.

Comment: I edited my comment once I re-read the question.  The link I posted for Regular Expressions is a good place to get started, but each regex is going to be unique to the situation.  In the example you just gave you would use `replaceAll('(\\s?\\|[^\\]]*)','')`

Comment: Haha @AverageJoeVBA sorry I got distracted trying to build a new RegEx for you.  Glad I could help. Leaving the new RegEx up though in case anyone else wants it.

Comment: Okay Now I'm getting Invalid string literal '(|.*\] )'. Illegal character sequence '\]' in string literal.

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out neex to double up the \\